# How to make conky list top 5 processes?

Tags: monitoring, conky

I don't like how **conky** shows top 5 processes with "$top_io name 5" parameter.
Is there any way to make conky show all of them in a column at the same time like "top" does?
Couldn't find it in man, maybe somebody will help.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Conky Variable Documentation](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html):

```
top_io  type num    Same as top, except sorted by the amount of I/O the process
                    has done during the update interval.
```

So it should be the same as top. Just specify what info you want.

Example:

```
${top_io name 1} ${top_io io_perc 1} ${top_io cpu 1} ${top_io mem 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just do it yourself:

Save this to a shell script;

```
#!/bin/bash
top -b -n1 | awk 'begin {print "pid","cpu","mem","cmd"} {print $1,$9,$10,$12}'
```

And call it from conky with whatever refresh interval you like;

```
${texeci 1 ~/path/to/shellscript.sh}
```

The shell script will need some tweaking to your preferences, but it should get you started.